# set bash variable from two nested programs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I need to run many times an aplication and get some statistcs using some commands. 
A simple exemple of what I'm traying to do is:

```
/usr/bin/time --format="%U" date
```

This line will print:

```
Seg Nov  2 22:15:28 BRST 2015
0.00
```

I need to format this output, and I want to do this using bash, like this:

```
echo "$usertime & $date"
```

where `$usertime` is the result from `/usr/bin/time --format="%U"` and `$date` the result of `date`

I know that the below works, but I don't know how to separate the values into two variables:

```
OUTPUT=`/usr/bin/time --format="%U" date`
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

the output from above is:

```
0.00
Seg Nov  2 22:23:50 BRST 2015
```

(in reverse order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using awk

Here, awk is used to reverse the line order and format the output:

```
$ /usr/bin/time --format="%U" date 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{d=$0;next} {print $0 " & " d}'
0.00 & Mon Nov  2 16:58:40 PST 2015
```

#### Using sed

```
$ /usr/bin/time --format="%U" date 2>&1 | sed -E 'N; s/([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\2 \& \1/'
0.00 & Mon Nov  2 17:01:15 PST 2015
```

#### Using shell

```
$ /usr/bin/time --format="%U" date 2>&1 | ( read d; read t; echo "$t & $d" )
0.00 & Mon Nov  2 17:04:40 PST 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/time is writing the time to standard error, whereas the output of date is going to standard output.  If you want them in separate variables, you can write the output of time to a file with the `-o` flag, then read it back in to another variable:

```
OUTPUT=`/usr/bin/time -o timefile --format="%U" date`
TIME=$(<timefile)
```